# Querying Database MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm learning MVC from sample application MVC Music Store. It has two database tables, one called 'Order' and the other 'OrderDetails'. If an order is made and a customer selects more than one item, after checkout each item bought creates a new row in the OrderDetails database and the OrderDetailsID will increment.

The OrderDetail database looks like:

```
http://imagebin.org/221494
```

I want to write a controller that will just pass all rows which have the same particular OrderId. For example, in that database there are 3 rows each with the same OrderId '3'.

How can I do this and pass it to a razor view? I've tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcMusicStore.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
public class OrderDetailsController : Controller
{
    private MusicStoreEntities db = new MusicStoreEntities();

          //
    // GET: /OrderDetails/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        OrderDetail orderdetail = db.OrderDetails.Find(id);
        if (orderdetail == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(orderdetail);
    }
```

This will return a single result based on OrderDetailsId and not several results all with the same OrderId. I should be able to visit ....:11091/orderdetails/Details/3 and see not one result but a list of three different albums and their prices.

Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want the LINQ query to do this.

**Original Answer (just the OrderItems)**

The following should suffice, but note that you will need to change your razor view Model type from `OrderDetail` to `IList<OrderDetail>`.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    var orderdetails = db.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.OrderId == id).ToList();
    if ((orderdetails == null) || (!orderdetails.Any()))
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(orderdetails);
}
```

**Edit**

Because you are now passing a collection to the view, you need to iterate through the items to render it. That said, it might actually make sense not to fetch just the `OrderDetails` for an `Order`, but instead, fetch the `Order` and `.Include()` all of the associated `OrderDetails`, and then pass the graph to the view. I've assumed that you've set up the relationship between `Order` and `OrderDetails` in Entity Framework.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
    var orderWithDetails = db.Orders
                             .Include(o => o.OrderDetails)
                             .FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderId == id);
    if (orderWithDetails == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(orderWithDetails);
}
```

**View**  (Takes the `Order` with the `OrderDetails` already eager-loaded)

```
@model MvcMusicStore.Models.Order
```

... Show Order level fields here

```
<div class="display-label">
   @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
</div>
<div class="display-field">
  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Username)
</div>
```

... Show OrderDetail level fields here, e.g. in a table or grid

```
@foreach (var orderItem in model.OrderDetails) {

  <div class="display-label">
       @Html.DisplayNameFor(orderItem => orderItem.OrderItemField1)
  </div>
  <div class="display-field">
      @Html.DisplayFor(orderItem => orderItem.OrderItemField1)
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your reply. There is still an error. Including the associated orderdetails is exactly what I want to do however.

Comment: Do you have a way to contact you privately? I'd like to send you the VS solution, I can pay you in advance via paypal. I've spent too much time trying to get this to work.

Comment: @user1448260 Post your project and I'll see what I can do. No payment needed :)

Comment: Thanks, i'll post it bit later today after work! Just want to be able to display particular order plus it's order details. It's almost 100% the default MVC Music Store solution but with some extra controllers.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of SQL, this would be (I have invented the field names)

```
select orderdetails.title, orderdetails.quant
from orderdetails inner join orders
on orderdetails.ord = orders.ord
where orders.ordname = :p1
```

P1 is a parameter which would accept the order's name/number

Comment: Do you know how to do it with LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

> public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
>
> ```
> {
>     OrderDetail orderdetail = db.OrderDetails.Where(o => o.Id == id).ToList();
>     if (orderdetail == null)
>     {
>         return HttpNotFound();
>     }
>     return View(orderdetail);
> }
> ```

In your view...

Depending on your Entity. Your view will use @model List

Then iterate thorugh the list:

> @foreach(var i in Model) {
>        Html.DisplayFor(x => i.Name)
>   }

or just YourProject.Model.xxx

> @foreach(var i in Model.YourList) {
>        Html.DisplayFor(x => i.Name)
>   }